# Problema ao imprimir próximos 10 números em sequência

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um exercício simples. Preciso ler um número do prompt e imprimir os 10 próximos na mesma linha, porém o código que criei só demonstra o último. Alguém sabe resolver?

```
var prompt=require('prompt-sync')()

var numero=Number(prompt('Número: '))

var seguintes= ''
for(var i=1; i<10; i++){
    seguintes=numero+i+', '
}
seguinte=numero+i
console.log(`Seguintes: ${seguintes}`)
```

Agradeço as respostas, ambas solucionaram essa dúvida, porém fiquei com uma dúvida maior, pois tenho uma resolução desse exercício que não utiliza esse acumulador "+=". o código a seguir foi testado e realmente funciona porém me inspirou a criar o código anterior e me deixou sinceramente confuso quanto a possibilidade de utilizar ou não o "+=".

```
var prompt=require('prompt-sync')()

var num=Number(prompt('Número: '))

var resposta = ''

for(var i=num+1; i<=num+10; i++){
    resposta = resposta + i + ', '
}
console.log(`Seguintes: ${resposta}`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O operado `+` quando é aplicado a objetos `Number` ele os soma.

Quando o operador `+` é aplicado entre `Strings` e `Numbers` ele converte os `Numbers` em `Strings` e concatena a sentença.

Apenas separe as operações numéricas com parenteses `()`.

```js
var numero = Number(prompt('Número: '))

var seguintes = ''


for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  seguintes += (numero + i) + ', '
}

seguintes += (numero + i)

console.log(`Seguintes: ${seguintes}`)
```

Answer (score 2):

O maior erro é que não está acumulando os textos, em cada passagem ele troca o texto, inclusive na última é só o que está guardado na variável. O operador `=` atribuiu um valor à variável, o `+=` atribui um valor à variável considerando o valor já existente, então ele é um acumulador, que é o que deseja em todos os casos.

Como pode ser visto não é necessário parênteses.

Eu preferi usar o literal 10 e não o `i`. Em JS funciona com `var`, mas não funciona com `let`. E isto é considerado uma falha da linguagem deixar vazar a variável no escopo, então eu acho melhor acostumar com o escopo correto sempre.

Coloquei os `;` porque embora funcione neste caso você vai se acostumar errado e quando der problema pela falta dele ficará bem perdido, acostume-se fazer um código organizado e programará melhor.

```js
var numero = Number(prompt('Número: '));
var seguintes = '';
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) seguintes += numero + i + ', ';
seguintes += numero + 10;
console.log(`Seguintes: ${seguintes}`);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Concatenation.js).